# How to set value of an enum member of a structure

Tags: c

The structure's code that is giving me problems is

```
typedef struct gamer
{
    char name[MAXNAME];
    Cell token;
    unsigned score;
} Gamer;
```

The enum is

```
typedef enum cell
{
    BLANK, RED, CYAN
} Cell;
```

When I try to set the value of my struct `Cell` member I use this code;

```
 gamer1->Cell = RED;
```

however when compiling it gives me this error;

```
error: 'Gamer' has no member named 'Cell'". Thanks in advanced.
```

Comment: The name of the member is `token`. `Cell` is its datatype.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do  `gamer1->token = RED;`

`token` is the member of the struct and not `Cell`.

Comment: Thanks dude, after all it was something so simple... :(